# Open link in new tab does not work in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I am using window.open in jquery to open a link in a new tab. Works fine for me in chrome/safari/firefox, but it does not work in IE10.

```
$('.div').click(function() {
    $(this).target = "_blank";
    window.open('http://url/15M');
    return false;
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This depends on the browser settings, and is not something you can force! As a sidenote, target is probably not a jQuery method, but a native property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open url in new tab using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

Comment: It's not possible to force/set with Javascript - it's up to the browser's settings. What are you trying to do with `$(this).target = "_blank";`?

Comment: @Ian the target is supposed to open the window in a new tab. This is my poor way of writing it. What Marek Lewandowski and mcpDESIGNS suggested is probably a much better way of doing it, however when clicked IE10 still does not open the link and treats it as href="#"

Comment: @agassi0430 The way the answers suggest it is the *correct* way to open a new window/tab. It doesn't matter what "target" you set, you can't explicitly choose between opening a window or a tab. All you can do is say "Open whatever the browser's settings say to open". By default, most browsers open a new tab, but can easily be changed by the user. Long story short, you can control this with Javascript, as we've already pointed out, and as the duplicate question, I mentioned, has. In your code, `$(this)` refers to the specific `.div` element clicked, which is unrelated to `window.open`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser itself will decide when it's appropriate to open a new tab versus a new window, though you can influence its decision via [browser settings](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-vista/tabbed-browsing-frequently-asked-questions). That being said, there are often times certain things we can do to encourage one way over the other. In this particular instance, I was able to get IE10 to open a window by passing along width and height values:

```
$("button").on("click", function () {
    window.open("http://msdn.microsoft.com", "popup", "width=640,height=480");
});
```

Keep in mind that you ultimately have no control over whether something opens in a new tab, or a new window. That is entirely up to the user's machine; so don't bake any user experience dependencies into this assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
$('.div').click(function() {
    window.open('http://url/15M', '_blank');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Better way of writing what I was trying to do, however when clicked IE10 still does not open the link and treats it as href="#"